# Rails: Calling to_json method in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How would I call .to_json on data-filters below?

```
data-filters="<%= t.AB_filterRules %>"
```

The reason I ask is because I have the data-filters attribute in my HTML ERB file, and it displays the database attributes. Example below:

```
data-filters="[[{" noun":"app","comparison":"was","value":”opened in the last two days"},{"noun":"deliverable","comparison":"is","value":"push notification"}]]"
```

However, when I view the value of the data-filters attribute in console, it only shows:

```
"[[{"
```

I'd really like it all to be displayed, so calling .to_json would be very helpful here!

Thanks

Comment: Can you add, to your question, what is an example value of  `t.AB_filterRules` in ruby, and what raw html you would like to end up with for that example?

Comment: It's probably going to be either `<%= h t.AB_filterRules %>` or `<%= t.AB_filterRules.inspect %>` tho.

Comment: Hi Max, the example in the question displays the raw value I'm expecting.

Comment: Including the webquote and the extra space at the start of `" noun"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing to bear in mind thinking about this is: If this is destined to be read by a javascript function, and converted back into a javascript object, then it can be rendered out onto the page **in any way whatsoever, as long as that can be translated back again in the javascript function**.

We'll be doing the "object to string" translation in ruby, and the "string to object" translation in javascript, so we'll need to pick some translation system which works in a standard way in both languages.  I'm going with `URI.escape` in ruby, and `decodeURIComponent` for the reverse in javascript.  `URI.escape` is a standard system (meaning the rules should be the same across different languages) and is web-safe, meaning the result shouldn't have any characters that will break a url or html tag.

in the erb template:

```
<% @rules = [[{" noun" => "app","comparison" => "was","value" => "opened in the last two days"},{"noun" => "deliverable","comparison" => "is","value" =>"push notification"}]] %>

<div id="data-filters-test" data-filters="<%= URI.escape(@rules.to_json) %>"></div>
```

Obviously you can replace @rules with your own method that reads the data from the database or whatever: the above is just my version so i could test it.

resultant html:

```
<div id="data-filters-test" data-filters="[[%7B%22value%22:%22opened%20in%20the%20last%20two%20days%22,%22%20noun%22:%22app%22,%22comparison%22:%22was%22%7D,%7B%22noun%22:%22deliverable%22,%22value%22:%22push%20notification%22,%22comparison%22:%22is%22%7D]]"></div>
```

Your final step will be to translate this back from the `URI.escape`'d string into an object, in your javascript.  I would do this like so: (the following lists the results of each step, for explanation)

```
//get the string
var escapedString = $("#data-filters-test").data("filters");
// => "[[%7B%22value%22:%22opened%20in%20the%20last%20two%20days%22,%22%20noun%22:%22app%22,%22comparison%22:%22was%22%7D,%7B%22noun%22:%22deliverable%22,%22value%22:%22push%20notification%22,%22comparison%22:%22is%22%7D]]"

//reverse the URI.escape, to get it back to json
var json = decodeURIComponent(escapedString);
// => "[[{"value":"opened in the last two days"," noun":"app","comparison":"was"},{"noun":"deliverable","value":"push notification","comparison":"is"}]]"

//convert the json string to a javascript object
var filter = JSON.parse(json);
// => <Object>
```

Obviously you could wrap this all up in a single step if you wanted, or, even better, a function, eg

```
function uriEscapedToObject(escapedString){
  return JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(escapedString));
}
```

Now in your js to handle this element you can write

```
var filters = uriEscapedToObject($("#data-filters-test").data("filters"));
```